# What if the production editor does not respond to important email after a few days?

Tags: proofreading, copy-editing

I sent my review of the proof for an article back to the production editor. However, due to the large amount minor corrections I made (roughly 50), I requested a second review. I sent two emails. But now it has already 4 days, and there is no response from the production editor.

I am so nervous because if the typesetter corrects the manuscript inappropriately or even publishes the paper without fully addressing the correction, it would be too late to do any further action.

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: How did you end up with 50 corrections? Does that imply that the version of the paper you submitted wasn't proof-read?

Comment: Thanks Wofgang for your reply. No, not all my fault. Some are caused during the proofreading process. The production editor replied me and said he would give me the revised version once they finished...So that's a good sign. However, during this period, I spotted three more (minor, but mine errors)... Should I tell him now? Or should I wait the revised version and give back to him at that time?

Comment: In all likelihood telling him now will be pretty pointless, since the manuscript is with the typesetters, not the production editor, so he can't do anything. But this - continuously finding minor errors - is exactly the kind of thing which will annoy production editors. I recommend finding all the minor errors you can right now, and send no more new corrections after the next revision.

Comment: Thank you Allure, and your answers are always helpful!

Comment: @Allure, just give you an update. After the production editor agrees to send me the revised proof back, he sent the article directly to the academic editor and therefore the manuscript is on hold now. I have not yet pointed out the other three errors yet. I am too nervous as I do not know what will happen, especially maybe the academic editor might reject the manuscript...

Comment: @MikeChen would be weird, unless the academic contents of the manuscript changed the academic editor is not likely to change their mind. It's odd for the production editor to send the manuscript to the academic editor instead of liaise with you directly - can't tell if it's because of it's the publisher's standard operating procedure, or if the production editor is inexperienced.

Comment: @Allure, I guess the reason might be what I took as minor correction is regarded as major correction by production editor, so that he cannot decide whether to make the correction or not. So... there might be a possibility that the editor in chief rejects the article....I am so stupid.

Comment: @MikeChen unless you really attempted something major (like deleting entire sections), *relax*. I'll metaphorically eat my hat if the editor-in-chief rejects your article.

Answer (score 3):

It's been four days, and that might also include a weekend day depending on where in the world the production editor is. Have patience, and let the process work itself out :-)

Comment: Thanks Wofgang for your reply. No, not all my fault. Some are caused during the proofreading process. The production editor replied me and said he would give me the revised version once they finished...So that's a good sign. However, during this period, I spotted three more (minor, but mine errors)... Should I tell him now? Or should I wait the revised version and give back to him at that time?

Comment: @MikeChen: Yes, tell him.